# jQuery mouseenter not working on entire span when a link is present

Tags: jquery

MY fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8DgUk/

As you can see, if you change the text value, then I want a red warning to appear. When they hover over either the link or the text "Warning" I want the warning message to appear.

To accomplish this, I wrapped everything in a div with a custom id. You would think that by hovering over the text in that div it should trigger, but it only triggers when the link anchor text is hovered.

How can I get the entire div#add_test_warning to be a mouseenter target?

My jquery code

```
$('input').change(function () {
    $("#addtest").wrap("<div id='add_test_warning'></div>");
    $('#addtest').after(' <span style="color:red;font-weight:bold">Warning</span>');
    $('#add_test_warning').after('<span id="warningmessage" style="width:100%;display:none">Current split test settings have changed. Please save your settings before adding a new test.</span>');
});

$('#add_test_warning,#addtest').mouseenter(function () {
    $('#warningmessage').fadeIn();
});

$('#add_test_warning,#addtest').mouseleave(function () {
    $('#warningmessage').fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind events on dynamically inserted elements using .on

```
$('input').change(function () {
    $("#addtest").wrap("<div id='add_test_warning'></div>");
    $('#addtest').after(' <span style="color:red;font-weight:bold">Warning</span>');
    $('#add_test_warning').after('<span id="warningmessage" style="width:100%;display:none">Current split test settings have changed. Please save your settings before adding a new test.</span>');
});

// This line has to be changed
$(document).on('mouseenter', '#addtest, span', function() {
    $('#warningmessage').fadeIn();
});

$('#add_test_warning,#addtest').mouseleave(function () {
    $('#warningmessage').fadeOut();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k5bs5/